# Select distinct first words of a field

Tags: mysql, select

i would like to be able to do a select query, taking only the distinct first words of the string, excluding the last one. If not clear, here is the result i'd like to have for the following table :

**Apple iPhone 4S

Apple iPhone 4

Apple iPhone 6 Plus**

```
              +-----------+--------------------------------+
              |    id     |             model              |
              +-----------+--------------------------------+
              |     1     |      Apple iPhone 4S 16Gb      |
              |     2     |      Apple iPhone 4S 32Gb      |
              |     3     |       Apple iPhone 4 8Gb       |
              |     4     |    Apple iPhone 6 Plus 32Gb    |
              |     5     |    Apple iPhone 6 Plus 64Gb    |
              +-----------+--------------------------------+
```

How to select the distinct values of the field while excluding the values after the last space ?

I tried to find documentation about functions like a sort of 
**right(model, lastindexof(" "))**.
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reverse the string to find the first space `" "`

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/BGOF98049)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(`model`),LOCATE(" ",REVERSE(`model`)))))
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: This is generic and the more correct way of doing it .

Comment: @sagi if only they make the reverse search function would be much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, that is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTRING(model, 1, LENGTH(TRIM(model))-4))
```

Comment: There may be more efficient ways, but that should work

Comment: Why `-4` ? doesnt look too generic

Comment: It looks like all the records end with a space followed by the HD size. The HD size is always at least 3 characters. So removing the last 4 characters and then trimming should get everything before the last space

Comment: So when Apple release the 128 GB model query will broke?

Comment: @CptMisery What about `128GB` ?

Comment: But no one will pay for their cloud service with that much space

Comment: This was just the first thing I thought of and it works for the data I was given

Comment: Yup:P @JuanCarlosOropeza . Cpt, everything is fine, but in this case it seems quite necessary to make the query generic since you can't know the format of each and every phone model. (Not only IPhones?)