# Select with the %LIKE% clause and excluding results containing certain words

Tags: mysql, select

I've recently made this thread to manage iPhone models in a database to be able to select all the different models by excluding the last word (which is the capacity).

[Select distinct first words of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404246/select-distinct-first-words-of-a-field/40404410#40404410)

```
          +-----------+--------------------------------+
          |    id     |             model              |
          +-----------+--------------------------------+
          |     1     |      Apple iPhone 4S 16Gb      |
          |     2     |      Apple iPhone 4S 32Gb      |
          |     3     |       Apple iPhone 4 8Gb       |
          |     4     |    Apple iPhone 6 Plus 32Gb    |
          |     5     |    Apple iPhone 6 Plus 64Gb    |
          |     6     |       Apple iPhone 6 16Gb      |
          +-----------+--------------------------------+
```

For this table, i had the following output : 
**Apple iPhone 4S

Apple iPhone 4

Apple iPhone 6 Plus

Apple iPhone 6**

Now, i'd like to be able, for each model, to get the available capacities.
I was thinking about using the LIKE %% clause,

```
SELECT * FROM  `model` WHERE  `value_model` LIKE  '%Apple iPhone 6S%'
```

It was working until the models with a 'Plus' appeared.
for the iPhone 4S for exemple i just had to do the following :

```
SELECT * FROM  `model` WHERE  `value_model` LIKE  '%Apple iPhone 4S%'
```

I had this input :
 
**Apple iPhone 4S 16Gb 

Apple iPhone 4S 32Gb**

But for the iPhone 6, it would also include the iPhone 6 Plus in my results.

How could i come across this, by excluding the results with a 'Plus', but also be able to not exclude this 'Plus' when i'm asking for a 'Plus' model.

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Could you write the output that you're looking for ?

Comment: Just get the results of a given model.
For the iPhone 4S : 
Apple iPhone 4S 16Gb, Apple iPhone 4S 32Gb

For the iPhone 6 : 
Apple iPhone 6 16Gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi This is the perfect solution for you

```
SELECT * FROM  `model`
WHERE TRIM(REPLACE(NAME,SUBSTRING_INDEX(value_model,' ',-1),'')) LIKE  '%Apple iPhone 6'
```

Comment: Please mark it as right answer if you think it usefull

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly :

```
SELECT * FROM  `model` WHERE  `value_model` LIKE  '%Apple iPhone 6%' and `value_model` NOT LIKE  '%Apple iPhone 6 Plus%'
```

Comment: That was the query i tried, but i get this output even with the "NOT LIKE" : 
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/754824output.png