# How to get different data from string using distinct + get total of each data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

Good Day!
Im new here.
I have problem showing data from one field 'activity'.
field 'activity' has string that separated by commas
"Penunjang pelaksanaan pekerjaan,Pelaksanaan pelayanan masyarakat,Pembelajaran" --> possible input.

I want to select them use distinct so I can get like table below

```
          +-----------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
          |    id     |             List_summary        |      Total      |
          +-----------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
          |     1     | Penunjang pelaksanaan pekerjaan |       8         |
          |     2     | Pelaksanaan pelayanan masyarakat|       9         |
          |     3     |            Pembelajaran         |       7         |
          +-----------+---------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Im quite new with php and I get confuse with documentation.
Please kindly help me.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I might be way off here, if I understand you correctly, then you're afraid that your comma's will mess with the SQL?

The best way is to use PHP's [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

But if you want to do it the manual way (as it appears that you are), - then you could [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the text, before you put it into the query.

Ex.

```
$test = serialize( 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf!@#$%!@' );
echo $test
```

Produces:

```
s:27:"asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf!@#$%!@";
```

... Safe for queries.

Comment: can you please expand it with queries?
I want something like
SELECT distinct(activity) aslist_summary,
COUNT(DISTINCT activity`) AS list FROM table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404246/select-distinct-first-words-of-a-field
more like this but with comma